# Authority in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, authority

I'm trying to put a system together where there are some teams that are managed by moderator(s) and admins.

What I want to setup is that when you create an team, you are the admin of that team, you can define who can add / delete users, ...

there are overal admins who can also edit every team, and such

I have all models setup and such with laravel as framework. I tried installing [Authority-L4](https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4) and that is running, but nowhere there is any documentation (or what I can find) on how to give users rights, it's easy to find on how to check if a users has them, but I can't seem to find how to define them

So what would be the command to run if I want user `dummy` to have edit rights on team `awesome` and user `SuperDummy` to have edit and delete rights on team `awesome`

And preferably how can I also define these things in my seeds

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to start building a system with multiple roles.
To get you started with a good package you can have a look at Sentry for Laravel 4.
 [Sentry For Laravel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry#laravel-4)

**Some demo's:**

https://github.com/rydurham/L4withSentry

https://github.com/cartalyst/demo-sentry

Comment: Looks not bad, but that would require that I redo, most of my work, and the only benefit is that I then can have permission groups (witch I can create for each team) I think creating my own role system would be less work. imho.